# Big Integer looping number calculation

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know why does it only run the code once and not every time the button is clicked? As a result, it always shows 12

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BigInteger example1 = new BigInteger("120");
            BigInteger example2 = new BigInteger("100");

            BigInteger example3 = new BigInteger("10");

            example3 = (example3.multiply(example1).divide(example2));

            String example4 = String.valueOf(example3);

            testb.setText(example4);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It always shows 12 because 10×120÷100 is always equal to 12. What else were you expecting?

Comment: In order to produce different results you'd need to include some other mutable variable in the calculation/equation from outside the scope of these local variables.

Comment: @khelwood well I was expecting it would be 12x120÷100

Comment: Then you need to save the updated value of `example3` instead of creating `example3` new and setting it to 10 each time the method is called. You should also explain clearly and in detail what you want the method to do in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually calculating: 1200 / 100 -> resulting, the result is 12.
And if you click on the same button again, the BigInteger example3 is setting back 10. If you want that the variables don't reset for every button click you need to declare them out of the onClick Method! Like this:

```
private BigInteger example1 = new BigInteger("120");
private BigInteger example2 = new BigInteger("100");
private BigInteger example3 = new BigInteger("10");

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
example3 = (example3.multiply(example1).divide(example2));
testb.setText(String.valueOf(example3));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As in the above answer, every time you click the button, the value of example3 is saved as a new one.
If you want 12 to continue printing as you wish, you will have to press the button, exit the program, and run it again.